# CSS two ul>li elements per line

Tags: css

I have a list of elements and I am trying to display them two per line. I've tried to use display:block to have them display one per line as a first step, but it doesn't seem to work.

What am I missing?

```css
.legend { list-style: none; }
.legend li {float: left; margin-right: 1%; }
.legend span {display:block; float: left; width:10px; height:10px; margin: 1%; }
/* your colors */
.legend .available {background-color: #8bc34a; }
.legend .yourRequest {background-color: #ffee58; }
.legend .yourSession {background-color: #ef5350; }
.legend .unavailable {background-color: #bdbdbd; }
```

```html
<ul class="legend">
  <li><span class="available"></span> Available</li>
  <li><span class="yourRequest"></span> Your Request </li>
  <li><span class="yourSession"></span> Your Session </li>
  <li><span class="unavailable">       
  </span> Unavailable</li>
</ul>
```

[jsFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ogsv5v4q/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just give them a width of 50% (49% + 1% of margin):

```css
.legend { list-style: none; }
.legend li {display:block; float: left; margin-right: 1%; width: 49%; }
.legend span {float: left; width:10px; height:10px; margin: 1%; }
/* your colors */
.legend .available { background-color: #8bc34a; }
.legend .yourRequest { background-color: #ffee58; }
.legend .yourSession { background-color: #ef5350; }
.legend .unavailable { background-color: #bdbdbd; }
```

```html
<ul class="legend">
  <li><span class="available"></span>Available</li>
  <li><span class="yourRequest"></span>Your Request (Click to see details)</li>
  <li><span class="yourSession"></span> Your Session (Click to see details)</li>
  <li><span class="unavailable"></span>Unavailable</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) property will allow you to automatically divide list items into columns with little effort.

```css
.legend {
  columns: 2;
}
.legend span {display:block; float: left; width:10px; height:10px; margin: 1%; }
/* your colors */
.legend .available {background-color: #8bc34a; }
.legend .yourRequest {background-color: #ffee58; }
.legend .yourSession {background-color: #ef5350; }
.legend .unavailable {background-color: #bdbdbd; }
```

```html
<ul class="legend">
  <li><span class="available"></span>Available</li>
  <li><span class="yourRequest"></span>Your Request (Click to see details)</li>
  <li><span class="yourSession"></span> Your Session (Click to see details)</li>
  <li><span class="unavailable">       
  </span>Unavailable</li>
</ul>
```

Of course this will order items down and then to the right as:

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

rather than

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Comment: other options include `float`, `flexbox` and `grid`, which I may write up examples for later.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it only moves to a new line when a column's width is filled (right?). It might work better if I can set the element's width to fit the column. Will work around it now and update you.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the following line

`.legend li {float: left; margin-right: 1%; }`

to this

`.legend li {float: left; clear: both; margin-right: 1%; }`

so that it will display one block per line.

Comment: Just to understand what float:left & clear:both do: the first makes all elements stick to the left, and the second doesn't allow any other floating element on either side of the first. This way elements end up one in a line. Smart, thank you!